# XAML: binding in nested styles

Tags: xaml, binding, nested, styles

Is there a way to create a binding between a property and a nested `Style`? I have a `ResourceDictionary` with the following code (which doesn't work):

```xml
<Setter Property="MajorGridLineStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding MajorGridLineStroke, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="{Binding MajorGridLineStrokeThickness, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="StrokeDashArray" Value="10 5"/>-->
        </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

How can I have a `Binding` between my `DataContext` and the inner `Style` of my `MajorGridLineStyle`?

Comment: Why isn't it working? What is the error? Also, is the `Setter` you're showing part of a `Style`? In which case, why would you have nested `Styles` like this?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working. It doesn't generate an error but it also doesn't apply the style. The property 'MajorGridLineStyle' is a Style from a third party library so I don't see an other way to do this other than to have nested Styles.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17221/37/axis-gridlinesstyle-dynamicresource-or-style-binding-doesnt-work.

I don't know why this article didn't show up before but it's fixed now. I just create a new Style when the properties are changed.